# What can i delete from my phone (android adb)

Tags: applications, malware, delete

i am having problems with sone ads on my phone and i don't know what to delete anymore... i've already deleted on my DOGEE x5 phone

com.gangyun.beautysnap

com.lbe.parallel.intl

cn.xender

com.adups.fota.sysoper

com.vanzo.dreams.video

com.opera.branding

com.adups.fota

and now i have this...

https://pastebin.com/nDFu8YJQ

any advices? thanks

EDIT: these are the ads

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gMgL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ads usually appear on your phone because you have downloaded a free app which is now sending ads to you.

There are many possibilities as to which app is the culprit in your case, it can be a flashlight app, it could be a fake antivirus app, it could be a game etc...

There is an app that claims to be able to find which apps have the ability to send ads. It's called [anti adware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keerby.adaware). After downloading, go into the app and select 'scan now' and it will let you know which apps you might want to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in settings which apps have permission to "draw over other apps". You will find the culprit there.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Dr. Web Antivirus, Scan the phone. It might even be some system apps, a few framework files and one or two binaries and libraries. Everything the antivirus tells you just root it and delete it and you'll do away with the Adware. Once helped my Sony Xperia Z